# KSH String formatting issue

Tags: scripting, formatting, ksh

I have a conversion function in a KSH script:

```
function convert_string_to_seconds
{
    # $1: time as a string e.g. 200s (for 200 seconds)
    # output: $time_in_seconds containing the input string converted into seconds
    
    typeset timeselector input numeral
    typeset -i in
    
    input=$1
    numeral=$(print ${input%?})
    timeselector=$(print ${input#${input%%?}})
    case $timeselector in
        ("s")
            time_in_seconds=$numeral
            break ;;
        ("m")
            time_in_seconds=$(( $numeral * 60 ))
            break ;;
        ("h")
            time_in_seconds=$(( $numeral * 3600 ))
            break ;;
        (*)
            exit 7
            ;;
    esac

}
```

The value is coming from a configuration file which has a line like this:

```
MAXRECOVERY=200s
```

The code capturing the value is:

```
value=$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f 2)
```

If I'm running `convert_string_to_seconds $value`, then `input=200s`, `numerals=200s` and `timeselector=""`
If I run `convert_string_to_seconds 200s`, then `input=200s`, `numerals=200` and `timeselector=s`

If I run `echo "|${value}|"`, I'm getting `|200s|` so there is no space, \n or anything like that.

What am I missing?

Tried:

```
input=$1
input="$1"
input=$(printf '%s\n' "$1")
```

```
numeral=$(print ${value%?})
numeral=$(print ${value%?} | tr -d "\r")
```

```
timeselector=$(echo $value | sed 's/.*\(.\)/\1/')
timeselector=$(print ${value#${value%%?}} | tr -d "\r")
```

Answer (score 0):

despite having `echo "|"$input"|"` returns `|200s|`, it looks like there is a **\r** hidden in my input so replacing `input=$1` by `input=$(echo $1 | tr -d "\r")` fixes the issue